How to retrieve metadata from grpc response using grpcdynamic from github.com/jhump/protoreflect
Does anyone know how to get the incoming metadata from the server after making a grpc invoke call in client like
response, err := grpcClient.InvokeRpc(context.TODO(), methodDesc, message)
I am using https://github.com/jhump/protoreflect, you can refer to a sample code
here.

I found the solution, I just have to pass the additional arguments asking for metadata, Check this!. Also it has nothing to do with github.com/jhump/protoreflect
var header, trailer metadata.MD // variable to store header and trailer
r, err := client.SomeRPC(
ctx,
someRequest,
grpc.Header(&header),    // will retrieve header
grpc.Trailer(&trailer),  // will retrieve trailer
)

// do something with header and trailer

